# Google Drive API migration to REST API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Since Google is deprecating the Android API, I am trying to migrate to REST API.

My app uses Google Drive to save User's data.

The User have two options for backup (manual and schedule).

The User select an account and it is stored in the app (The email).

When needed, the app uses the account to connect to Google Drive and save/delete data.

To select which account to use the app is using the AccountPicker.

Once an account is selected, the app uses only the account in order to connect to Google Drive (See code below).

I would like to keep the current mechanism (The user select an account and when needed the app uses that account to connect to Google Drive).

I looked at the [sample](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVTB1jnQ0AjuIRI6msZfditKanj5oOmtDJM5Sv4VuuhF_YeT9agx0u9L_DDBje9x9Vz8SH0LtjAVAnhUshqrCm3vJu_HLQ3AR2L3r-8NxZi1ig4RRBnXBBJoY9VDomx7dTFy4wq3hjVPCg09MWA8) program and [migration](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVShuXS6QodZ1J47RcJ1ywwwbGEtTaIk2yBJ_xJhCKD4FMbCDVi-WJ3lZmXex5i9GR0BZA0eNRI110zlEUBR5AV0wcxLkYp1lEhBhO7Ls6we8L9p0rwAqNxv6Q) documentation, but did not figure out how to do it.

It seems that in the sample app, the prompt for an account with a dedicated activity and uses the returned data to sign in to Google Drive (not the behavior I need).

I did some code changes, but nothing worked (I got error **Drive connection failed (12500) 12500: 12500:  Error setting Google account.**). See below the modified code.

**Exiting Code**

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .setAccountName(accountName)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
client = builder.build();
client.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
client.registerConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                error = new DriveConnectException();
                if (result.hasResolution()) {
                    if (activity != null) {
                        try {
                            result.startResolutionForResult(activity, requestCode);
                            error = new InResolutionException();
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
client.connect();
try {
    latch.await();
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
if (client.isConnected()) {
    // do some work
} else {
    // report error
}
```

**Modified code**

```
GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .setAccountName(accountName)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .build();
client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions);
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = client.silentSignIn();
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    signInAccount = task.getResult();
} else {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
            try {
                signInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // I always ends up here.
            }
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. The active sign in works but I need it also for automatic "backup upload". So I want to sign in ones and uses this client to upload the files in the background.

Comment: No I did not, still waiting.

Comment: Just found a solution see my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know if it works for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to sign in the user:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, signInOptions);

    // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), RC_CODE_SIGN_IN);
```

In the onActivityResult:

```
GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
                        HyperLog.i(TAG, "Signed in as " + googleSignInAccount.getEmail());
                        mDriveServiceHelper = getDriveServiceHelper(googleSignInAccount);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        HyperLog.e(TAG, "Unable to sign in!", e);
                    }
                });
```

Ones the user was signed in you can retrieve the last Google Sign In Account with:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
```

And to get your DriveServiceHelper you can use the account you have retrieved:

```
mDriveServiceHelper = getDriveServiceHelper(account);
```

The "getDriveServiceHelper" method looks like this:

```
private DriveServiceHelper getDriveServiceHelper(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
        // Use the authenticated account ot sign in to the Drive service
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                activity, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        credential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());

        Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(), credential)
                .setApplicationName("COL Reminder")
                .build();
        return new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
    }
```

Comment: I marked it as accepted although there is one major issue: All my existing users will have to go and reconfigure the Google Drive account. If anyone find a solution to that please share.

Comment: Yes of course because it is a different API. So I think there is no way to use the signed in data from the Android Drive API.