# Google Play Game Service and Google drive API deprecated

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-games

I'm working on a module for Godot Engine, it is called godot-android. You can found [this module here](https://github.com/xsellier/godotandroid). This module use the Google Drive API via the SnapshotClient to save games on google drive.

Since I'm using this module for one of my android game released earlier this year, I received an email from google about the deprecation of the Google Drive Android API saying that my app is using the google drive deprecated API.

So, I've started reading again the [Google Play Games Services documentation for android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames), but they did not update their documentation. Then, after several hours spent on [Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796718/google-drive-api-migration-to-rest-api)/[github migration guide](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation) to find out how to migrate that SnapshotClient, I've just hit a wall.

My first step was to upgrade all the dependencies of my modules to their latest versions, compile and see what is broken:

```
  com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6
  com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0
  com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.6
  com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
  com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0
  com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1
  com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0
  com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0
  com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0
```

And I was glad to see that everything worked fine. Step 2, change the code used to get access to the google drive API:

```
  public GoogleAuthentication(Activity p_activity) {
    activity = p_activity;

    String webclientId = activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id);
    GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(webclientId)
    // Since we are using SavedGames, we need to add the SCOPE_APPFOLDER to access Google Drive.
    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
    .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    .setViewForPopups(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content))
    .build();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  }
```

So, the game starts, I have the login popup asking for scopes (right ones), I click on authorize, and then I don't have access to my savegames. Adb logcat:

```
    E/Parcel  (  820): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
    E/Parcel  (  820): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
    E/Parcel  (  820): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.ScopeData
    E/Parcel  (  820): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.ScopeData
    E/Parcel  (  820): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
    E/Parcel  (  820): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2140)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5261)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1591)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1169)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4359)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4241)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:164)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2878)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    E/Parcel  (  820):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    E/Parcel  (  820): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/SignInConfiguration
    E/Parcel  (  820):  ... 18 more
    E/Parcel  (  820): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the root issue, scopes were not right:

```
public GoogleAuthentication(Activity p_activity) {
activity = p_activity;

String webclientId = activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id);
GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
.requestIdToken(webclientId)
// Since we are using SavedGames, we need to add the SCOPE_APPFOLDER to access Google Drive.
.requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
.requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
.build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
.addApi(Games.API)
.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
.setViewForPopups(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content))
.build();

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
```

This piece of code works well, I updated the github module, you can take a look [at the commit](https://github.com/binogure-studio/godotandroid/commit/3d99d39797c4a402c7997e4b4711c0c64438572c).